# Update SQL column using Rank() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with existing data.  For each unique value in the first column of this table, we have a column that is supposed to be in sequential order, but this table has gotten out of order.  I want to run a SQL statement that will put this second column back in order.  I was able to see the results I want with this SQL:

```
select FORMULA_ID, ATTRIB_CODE, ATTRIB_VAL, ATTRIB_ORDER,
rank() over (partition by formula_id order by attrib_code, attrib_val) AS WANT_THIS
from ATTRIB
```

Which yields:

```
 FORMULA_ID  ATTRIB_CODE          ATTRIB_VAL       ATTRIB_ORDER WANT_THIS
 ----------- -------------------- ---------------- ------------ ---------
 2791        C_BRAND              ROMAN HOLIDAY    3            1
 2791        C_ENDUSE             DINNER           4            2
 2791        C_ENDUSE             SNACK            6            3
 2791        C_ENDUSER            10-17            7            4
 2791        C_PRODTYPE           SALAD            13           5
 2791        C_RELIG              ANY              14           6
 2821        C_ALLERGEN           PEANUT           1            1
 2821        C_ALLERGEN           SOY              2            2
 2821        C_BRAND              ROMAN HOLIDAY    1            3
 2821        C_ENDUSE             DINNER           1            4
```

As you can see, the WANT_THIS column orders the rows and resets to 1 when it gets to a new FORMULA_ID.  But I don't know how to convert this into an UPDATE statement that will actually put the value in WANT_THIS into the column ATTRIB_ORDER.  Is there a way to convert the SQL above into an UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is one way:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  FORMULA_ID, 
            ATTRIB_CODE, 
            ATTRIB_VAL, 
            ATTRIB_ORDER,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY formula_id 
                         ORDER BY attrib_code, attrib_val) AS WANT_THIS
    FROM ATTRIB
)
UPDATE CTE
SET ATTRIB_ORDER = WANT_THIS;
```

Comment: are you actually updating the real table even if the statement says "UPDATE CTE SET..." ??

Comment: CTE is a view not a temporary table, so you can update the underlying table this way. CTE is used to delete duplicate records in the table using row_number where row_number <> 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on MySql server:

```
UPDATE attrib

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT formula_id, attrib_code, attrib_val,
  rank() over (partition by formula_id order by attrib_code, attrib_val) 
  want_this FROM attrib
) AS new_values

ON 

attrib.formula_id = new_values.formula_id AND 
attrib.attrib_code = new_values.attrib_code AND 
attrib_val = new_values.attrib_val

SET 

attrib_order = new_values.want_this
```

Short description: We are updating the attrib table. First we must calculate new_values using a subquery. Then we connect (LEFT JOIN) the subquery with existing attrib table. After the connection is made, we exactly know to which row want_this should be applied. The ON condition is long here and it would be better to use unique identifier if possible.